# Oracle APEX4.2.6 Interactive report Email option

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I've been trying to set the APEX interactive reports to send mails:

[image]

And setting up the apex instance email option with the right info:

[image]

As the oracle documentation stands, enabling network settings to the INTERNAL workspace SCHEMA ('APEX_040200'); here's the code I used to enable the network settings:

```
    DECLARE 
ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to '*' and give APEX_050100
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_050100 does not have the privilege yet.

  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_040200',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_040200', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
    'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
    'APEX_040200', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

still, nothing changed, when I click the SEND button, it just closes and the mail never arrives.

I'm currently using the oracle DB 11gR2 version.

I'll be grateful with any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the SMTP Host Address and Port, otherwise it doesn't know what server to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

So I find out why this wasn't working:

- Oracle Database must be 11.2.0.4.0 or later for this to work (Prior versions can't handle SSL/TLS protocols)
- APEX user (APEX_040200 in my case) must be in the ACL list with 'resolve' and 'connect' privileges.
- Must create a Wallet that contains the smtp provider security certificate. You can create your wallet using the [orapki](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asoappf.htm#i634246) command.

**Note:** all this must be done on the 'INTERNAL' workspace under "Manage Instance" > "Instance Settings" > Email/Wallet.

If you find some trouble with sending the email, be sure tu sign the email account configured with the server hosting de APEX application, it may be a security/trust issue with the smtp provider (very likely to happen with gmail and office365).

After this you should be able to send your interactive reports from with the email configured from your APEX application with no problems.